# Solution for Entry and textBox in Tkinter, CustomTkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, customtkinter

(My first time on this website)
Hello everyone, I was wondering if there is a way to create an Entry or something similar that can store a textVariable so I can save it in SQL. I've tried using a textBox but couldn't find a way to save the text or delete it.

P.S: Sorry if it's not clear, I'm using Google Translate to translate. XD

````py
self.variable_descripcion = ctk.StringVar()
        self.descripcion_texto = ctk.CTkEntry(self,
                                            width=560,
                                            height=230,
                                            border_width=4,
                                            corner_radius=4,
                                            textvariable=self.variable_descripcion,)
        self.descripcion_texto.place(x=305, y=355, anchor="n")```

I don't have a problem with the Entry widget, but it's for writing a lot of text. If it's an Entry, the text goes beyond the "box" and I don't know how to make it start from the beginning instead of the middle. XD

With the textBox, I didn't know how to save data and delete it inside it.

If there is a better way to do it, I would be delighted to learn that method.
````